# Cannot read property push of undefined Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

at first i got error in the IDE in the .push, i changed the listaOrdenada type to any, no error but i got error in the console, cannot read property push of undefined

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {HomePage} from "../home/home";
import {ElegiritemsPage} from "../elegiritems/elegiritems";
import {Articulo} from "../../Data/articulo.interface";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-lista-terminada',
  templateUrl: 'lista-terminada.html',
})
export class ListaTerminadaPage implements OnInit{
  home=HomePage;
  elegirItem=ElegiritemsPage;
  listaFinal : Articulo[] = [];
  listaOrdenada : Articulo[] = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.listaFinal = this.navParams.data;
    for (var i=0; i < this.listaFinal.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.listaFinal[i]);
      this.listaOrdenada[this.listaFinal[i +1].pasillo].push(this.listaFinal[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your're trying to access an array that doesn't exist.

```
this.listaOrdenada[this.listaFinal[i +1].pasillo].push(this.listaFinal[i]);
```

The `i + 1` is trying to access an index that's out of range.